# На Yii2 не подключается модуль

Tags: php, yii2

Создал новый модуль к нему соответственно новый контроллер и CRUD теперь что бы переключится на новое представление в документации написано что нужно задать переменную $defaultRoute со значением равным папке где хранятся представления.
Я задал ее в корневом файле модуля Module.php

```
public $defaultRoute = 'mainnews';
```

Но при переходе по пути site.ru\namemodule пишет 404 если убрать переменную то заходит на стандартную страничку нового модуля, может где то не так написал переменную к дефолтному представлению. в корне веб лежит стандартный хтачес для красивого урла и включен урл менеджер.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
#RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php


        'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' =>
                [
                    'news' => 'tratata/tratatanews',
                    'onenews' => 'tratata/onenews',
                ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ простой: забыл что если названия сложные то они идут через дефис нужно в дефолт роуте писать main-news и папка представлений тоже должна называться через дефис